# Is this an adapter design pattern correctly implemented? If not what am I missing?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, adapter

I made an effort to create an adapter design pattern. A simple interface using which users can connect to both old and modern media player.

The modern media player plays `mp4` format, whereas the old plays only `wav` format. Using the class mediaPlayerInterface users can play both media types.

If you feel this is not an adapter design pattern, please comment what is missing. How can I modify it to Adapter pattern? I am a little new to design patterns.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MediaPlayer
{
   public:
      virtual void playSong()=0;
};

class ModernMediaPlayer : public MediaPlayer
{
   public:
    void playSong( )
    {
        cout << "Playing from modern media player" << endl;
    }

};

class oldMediaPlayer: public MediaPlayer
{
   public:
    void playSong( )
    {
        cout << "Playing from old media player" << endl;
    }
};

class mediaPlayerInterface
{
   private:
       string fileType;

   public:
        mediaPlayerInterface(string fType)
        {
          fileType=fType;
        }

        MediaPlayer* getMediaPlayer( )
        {
             if (fileType == "mp4")
             {
                 return new ModernMediaPlayer;
             }
             else if (fileType == "wav")
             {
                 return new oldMediaPlayer;
             }
        }
};

int main()
{
   mediaPlayerInterface *mIface = new mediaPlayerInterface("mp4");
   MediaPlayer *mplayer = mIface->getMediaPlayer();

   mplayer->playSong();

   mIface = new mediaPlayerInterface("wav");
   mplayer = mIface->getMediaPlayer();

  mplayer->playSong();
}


Output:
Playing from modern media player
Playing from old media player
```

Comment: But what are you adapting, your both players have the same interface. You just built a factory to get them.

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda But isn't the interface a bridge between two incompatible media players? The old and the new one?

Comment: This is the factory pattern, not the adapter pattern. Nitpicking: Start your class names with a capital! [EDIT]: Your media players are perfectly compatible, since they have the same interface. Their implementation is different, but that's not what compatibility means in this context.

Comment: @kingsmasher1, well, the `oldPlayer` and the `newPlayer` are perfectly interchangeable -- they derive from the same base class.

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda Padon my dumb question. So, is just the base class being derived an issue? Can you please help me, to modify this to make it adapter? I am wondering what is missing here.  Thanks much.

Comment: @kingsmasher1, you need an adapter if you program against some common abstraction -- say, `MediaPlayer` -- and the thing you want to use there cannot implement it. So you make a 'wrapper' -- an adapter-- which implements the abstraction, inject your incompatible module in it, and let the wrapper delegate the calls to the injected guy.

Comment: If your modern media player (or the legacy one) has a different interface and you used your ModernMediaPlayer class to wrap it and translate playSong to a functionality that it has then that is the adapter pattern. For instance (this is just a contrived example ) your new media player might have a function  that expects a file name to play. Your adapter can be for instance that you get this file name from an external source such as a dialog or config file and still maintain the playSong function that clients of the player now use.

Comment: I explained Adapter Pattern nicely in my blog post - https://ramesh-java-design-patterns.blogspot.in/2017/12/adapter-design-pattern.html

Comment: @RameshFadatare Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of the adapter pattern. What's essential is that the AscSequenceControl has all required functionality, but it can not be connected to the MovementPlanner, since the interface isn't compatible. So the RouteSegmenter indeed "adapts" this. It has the right interface and its implementation just uses the AscSequenceControl.

[image]

So in your example: You have a MediaPlayer with a method: gotoTrack (int trackNr). But the class MediaPlayerUser wants to say: mediaPlayer.nextTrack () and mediaPlayer.previousTrack (). So you make a bridge class MediaPlayerBridge. It has an attribute mediaPlayer and method nextTrack that calls mediaPlayer.gotoTrack (++currentTrack) and a method previousTrack that calls mediaPlayer.gotoTrack (--currentTrack).

[image]

Comment: So, where exactly the notifyPause() comes from? I understand, that AscRouteSegmenter is the abstraction. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the basic idea of the Adapter pattern is (I don't know C++, so excuse me for the C# code) --

You program against an abstraction

```
interface IPlayer
{
    void Play();
    void Stop();
    void Shuffle();
}

class ModernPlayer : IPlayer
{
    void Play() { // plays }
    void Stop() { // stops }
    void Shuffle() { // shuffles }
}
```

So far so good. You use it in your code like

```
IPlayer player = GetPlayer(); // some way to get an abstract IPlayer 
player.Shuffle();
```

Then you realize that you need a different IPlayer implementation. You find a library which has a player, but it has a totally different set of functions.

```
class WeirdNamesPlayer
{
    void BeginPlayback() { // plays}
    void Terminate() { // stops }
    void Randomize() { // shuffles }
}
```

What you do is you create a "wrapper" which implements your `IPlayer`, and let it wrap your `WeirdNames` one.

```
class WeirdPlayerAdapter : IPlayer
{
    private readonly WeirdNamesPlayer weird;

    public WeirdPlayerAdapter(WeirdNamesPlayer weird)
    {
        this.weird = weird;
    }

    void Play()
    {
        this.weird.BeginPlayback();
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        this.weird.Terminate();
    }

    void Shuffle()
    {
        this.weird.Randomize();
    }
}
```

Now you are free to use your incompatible implementation in place of an `IPlayer` -- the adapter provides the required interface.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this helped as well.